# Why is this not an equivalence relation on real functions? $(\exists c\in\mathbb{R})(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})|f(x)-g(x)|=c$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Say we have the following relation on the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$(\exists c \in \mathbb{R})(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})|f(x) - g(x)| = c$$

I'm having trouble understanding why this relation isn't an equivalence relation.

I know that the relation is reflexive, as $f(x) - f(x) = 0$, $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

But I'm having trouble when it comes to symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: Symmetry follows at once from that absolute value there: $\;|f(x)-g(x)|=|g(x)-f(x)|\;$

Comment: ...and who says it isn't an equivalence relation? Why do you thin it isn't?

Comment: @DonAntonio It is not an equivalence relation if we consider also discontinuous function. For example $f(x) = 1, x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = -1, x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, is related to the null function. The null function is related to $g(x) = 1$. But $f$ is not related to $g$.

Comment: @DonAntonio This relation is defined on the set of all functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, not only continuous ones.

Comment: @mwt I know. I only wanted the OP to answer why he/she believes the relation isn't an equivalence one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $f(x)= -1$ if $x <0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geqslant 0$. Then $|f(x) - 0| = 1$ and $f$ is related to the null function.

The constant function $g(x) = 1$ is also related to the null function.

But $f$ and $g$ are not related as $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is non-constant!

I think if you restrict your relation on continuous functions, you avoid this kind of behavior and maybe it would define an equivalence relation on this set.

Comment: You're right and thanks for pointing out my mistake in my (now deleted) answer. Lack of sleep does that haha.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the relation is not transitive let's take three functions $f,g,h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 0 \\
g(x) &= \left\lbrace\begin{array}
--1 &\text{ for $x < 0$} \\
1 &\text{ for $x >= 0$} \\
\end{array}\right. \\
h(x) &= g(x) + 1
\end{align}

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|f(x) - g(x)| = 1$ and $|g(x) - h(x)| = 1$. However $|f(x) - h(x)|$ equals either $0$ (for $x < 0$) or $2$ (for $x >= 0$).